# how to disambiguate using @DocumentField in spring data mongoDB

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

While trying to save Object into mongo DB using Spring-Data MongoDB, I am getting this exception.

```
Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both <child class field> and <parent class field> map to the same field name <field name>! Disambiguate using @DocumentField annotation!
```

I am hiding a field in child class and this is causing the issue. But this is essential for me to hide the field declared in super class. I cannot find **@DocumentField** annotation anywhere. How can I proceed here? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I have the same issue since I would like to store base type in both mongodb   and neo4j. Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

For those of you (like me) who  arrived here due to another form of `Ambiguous field mapping detected!` error that is not quite the same as OP, consider that your child class may not even need a field at all and the answer provided by @sparm could be changed to:

```
public class Parent {
    private String myField;
    public getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }
}

@Document(collection = "children")
public class Child extends Parent {

    public getMyField() {
       super.getMyField();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe its an error in the exception. You need to use `@Field` instead and specify a different name for the parameter so:

```
public class Parent {
    private String myField;
}

@Document(collection = "children")
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Field("childField")
    private String myField;
}
```